# How to disable vqmod cache in Opencart 2.0?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

Hello is there way how to disable all vqmod cache on opencart 2.0?
I have tried clearing the cache from : vqmod/cache but it doesn't work.
This is why i need to disable all cache .

Comment: Deshi, Do you know what is the use of vqmod cache ? If you enable vqmod in your opencart then it will always comes files into your cache file. This is the structure of vqmode. Vqmod run the xml files and call the code into cache file. If you don't require cache files then you need to remove vqmod functionality.

Comment: @VipulJethva - that's not true, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily disable caching in vQmod though I'm not sure why you'd want to - I've only run into issues with this on sites with 100+ vQmods installed.  Generally it's not recommended.

To disable the cache simply edit **vqmod/vqmod/php** and set:

```
private static $_devMode = true;
```

In dev mode, vqmod will parse your xml files in real time which may be a bit slower and it will not use any cache files.